# Memory Layout Choice of N-Dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-layout

I've started writing a library for n-dimensional vectors.

There's a couple of design features that I would like to support in this
library:

- The memory layout is continuous. This is so that sharing memory, sending over a network, and saving to file is only a matter of passing a pointer.
- Different dimensions can support different element sizes (ie `[0][0]` may be `1` byte while `[1][0]` may be `2` bytes).

After drawing out some representations of what the memory layout
would look like for vectors of certain dimensions, I've realized that
there is two ways to layout the structure:

Here's the first way. Both representations are a visualization of
a [2][4][3] array.

```
 ---------------------------
| index             | 0:0:0 |
| elementSize       |       |
| elementCount      |       |
| expansionBoundary |       |
| slotCount         |       |
 ---------------------------
 ---------------------------
| index             | 1:0:0 |
| elementSize       |       |
| elementCount      |       |
| expansionBoundary |       |
| slotCount         |       |
 ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 0:0:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 0:1:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 0:2:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 0:3:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 1:0:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 1:1:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 1:2:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 1:3:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:0:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:0:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:0:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:1:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:1:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:1:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:2:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:2:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:2:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:3:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:3:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:3:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:0:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:0:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:0:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:1:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:1:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:1:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:2:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:2:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:2:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:3:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:3:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:3:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
```

Here's the second way.

```
 ---------------------------
| index             | 0:0:0 |
| elementSize       |       |
| elementCount      |       |
| expansionBoundary |       |
| slotCount         |       |
 ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 0:0:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:0:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:0:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:0:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 0:1:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:1:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:1:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:1:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 0:2:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:2:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:2:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:2:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 0:3:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:3:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:3:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 0:3:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
 ---------------------------
| index             | 1:0:0 |
| elementSize       |       |
| elementCount      |       |
| expansionBoundary |       |
| slotCount         |       |
 ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 1:0:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:0:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:0:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:0:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 1:1:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:1:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:1:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:1:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 1:2:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:2:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:2:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:2:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
     ---------------------------
    | index             | 1:3:0 |
    | elementSize       |       |
    | elementCount      |       |
    | expansionBoundary |       |
    | slotCount         |       |
     ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:3:0 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:3:1 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
         ---------------------------
        | Index             | 1:3:2 |
        | Element           |       |
         ---------------------------
```

Are there certain advantages/disadvantages in choosing one layout over the other?

Comment: The second variant improves locality for a specific "dimension", meaning that if the data is small enough you can get both the data and the metadata into a lower level cache. The first improves locality for metadata, and the locality for the data, but probably not both at the same time.

Comment: Can you please explain your diagrams?